# What does 7e0 actually do in Python?

Tags: python, operator-keyword

The title explains it all, I found this in a university resource but am wondering why this returns **7.0**.

Comment: 7 * 10^0 = 7 * 1 = 7

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation

Comment: Yes, but why is it returning 7.0 when it is 10^0 = 1 -> 7 * 1 = 7?

Comment: @jameshelou: Are you under the impression that 7.0 is mathematically unequal to 7?

Comment: In the context of the situation I'm looking at this in, the difference between 7 and 7.0 is important here -_- I'm not asking for mathematical equivalents, I am asking why is it returning 7.0 as opposed to 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it returns 7.0, not 7 as it is not an integer. It is a floating point literal, which is why it is 7.0.

```
>>> type(7e0)
<type 'float'>
```

Comment: Thank you, this was EXACTLY what I needed.

Comment: I'm glad that answered it for you. It's tricky in python as there are no explicit types. If you could accept the answer I'd appreciate it!

Comment: What do you mean by "there are no explicit types"? Also, 7e0 is not an operation, it's a [literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#floating).

Comment: python is dynamically typed. You don't define a type when you declare a variable. The type is defined by the object a variable name is tied to. I modified to indicate it is a literal, that was my mistake.